# read text based(bed) files, add new column to them save in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I tried to read 700 bed files and save them in one csv file. I don't have a problem with this part. I must add one column to each bedfile as barcode, this barcode is part of each file's name (file's name `TCGA-02-0047-01A-01R-1849-01`, barcode part is `TCGA-02-0047-01A`), each bedfile consists of 64000 rows. That means in the barcode column I repeat the same value 67000 times. The code I wrote kind of works but I'm stuck in the `for` loop and doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
import pyranges as pr
import pandas as pd
import os

H = ["chrom",  "chromStart", "chromEnd", "strand", "gene_symbol", "entrez_gene_id", "transcript_id" , "raw_count", "scaled_estimate", "normalized_count", "barcode"]
list = os.listdir("E:\\newdata")   
#extract the barcode 
code =[]
for f in list:
    x = '-'.join(f.split('-')[0:3])
    code.append(x)
print('2')  
 #find direction of each bed file
newList=[]
for i in range(len(list)):
    newList.append("E:\\newdata\\" + list[i])
print('3')  
#read the bed files one after another, save it in file and add barcode

for bed in newList: #bed file in newlist
    for n in code: #barcode for each bed files
        df = pr.read_bed(bed, as_df=True)
        df['barcode'] = n #add colum for each bed file
        filename = df.to_csv('E:\\data951.csv',mode ='a', header = H, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, I assume that a code is relative to a file. So you should not use nested loops (one for the files and one for the codes) but one single loop and use the code with same index. And a CSV file should only have one single header at the top. So I would use:

```
#read the bed files one after another, save it in file and add barcode
# create the csv file and add a header only on first file
header = H
mode = 'w'
for i, bed in enumerate(newList): #bed file in newlist and get its index for the code
    n = code[i]: # barcode associated with each bed files
    df = pr.read_bed(bed, as_df=True)
    df['barcode'] = n #add colum for each bed file
    header = None    # will append without any header for following files
    mode = 'a'
    df.to_csv('E:\\data951.csv',mode=mode, header = header, index=False)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it was so helpful and my problem solved.

Comment: @sotoodeh.n: Thanks for you comment. But if it solved your problem, you should accept the answer (the checkmark on the left). That way future readers know that the problem is solved.